# Jquery selector select option

Tags: javascript

I wrote a code that basically selects all `input[type="tel"], input[type="url"], select option, textarea` element like this:

```
$(this).find('input[type="text"], input[type="password"],
input[type="username"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], 
input[type="url"], select option, textarea').each(function(){
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-7">
   <select id="cluster" name="cluster" class="form-control col-md-12">
     <option value="css">CSS</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

But `select option` does not know. I tried it but it did not work

Comment: What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: Can you show sample HTML?

Comment: I want to find a select option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<form>
<input type="text" />
<input type="password" />
<input type="username" />
<input type="email" />
<input type="tel" />
<input type="url"  />
<select>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
</select>
<textarea></textarea>
```

JS

```
$('body').find('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="username"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], input[type="url"], select option, textarea').each(function(i,e){
    console.log(e)
})
```

Note: you can change $('body') by some parent of elements

Return

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="password" />
<input type="username" />
<input type="email" />
<input type="tel" />
<input type="url"  />
<option>a</option>
<option>b</option>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: We have a code. It's like this `parent_fieldset.find` I wrote `parent_fieldset.body.find`

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.